# Slackware: Firefox not found after using upgradepkg

Tags: package-management, upgrade, firefox, slackware

I'm trying to upgrade from Firefox 24.1 to the latest stable version of Firefox (42.0). Here's what I did:

```
#tar -xf firefox.tarball
#cd ./extracted/firefox/files
#makepkg -p -l y ../firefox42.tgz
#cd ..
#upgradepkg old.firefox%firefox42.tgz
```

Afterwards, I'm informed that the upgrade is complete (I hesitate to say 'successful'), and firefox42 is listed in /var/log/packages.

When I run:

`$firefox`

or

`$firefox42`

in the terminal I get `command not found`.

What gives?

Comment: Your tarball is the one provided by mozilla, I presume? That one doesn't distribute itself over `/usr/bin`, `/usr/lib` etc. Can you check if you now unexpectedly have a `firefox` directory in `/`?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz, I have way more than a firefox directory in `/`. It looks like the entire mozilla tarball has been unpacked in `/`, which is _very_ unexpected.

Comment: @HandsomeGorilla please do not put "[SOLVED]" in the question title.  If an answer solves your problem, indicate that by clicking the checkmark next to the answer that fixed your problem.

Answer (score 1):

A Slackware package is essentially an archive designed to be unpacked at the root of your filesystem (plus an additional `/install` folder that contains a bit of metadata, such as a postinstall script `doinst.sh`).

So what has probably happened is that you were inside the directory that contains the `firefox` binary etc. when you ran `makepkg`.

IMO, I'd be lazy and unpack the files into `/tmp/x/opt/firefox`, create a symlink `/tmp/x/usr/bin/firefox-42` to `/tmp/x/opt/firefox/firefox` and run `makepkg` in `/tmp/x`. (This is lazy because it won't stick to the split into `/usr` etc., but if you already start out with a pre-compiled firefox that might assume everything it needs is in the same folder anyway, this might be good enough for you.)

Comment: I switched over to Slackware because of the adage 'if you know slackware, you know linux' (though, being a lowly n00b, I can't speak to the veracity of that statement), and I consider being competent at compiling from source to be a core skill.  Consequently, I've just got a raw source code tarball without any pre-compiled binaries

Comment: @HandsomeGorilla: Ah, OK, I understand the sentiment. FWIW, you can also look at [the script that slackware itself uses to build firefox](ftp://ftp.slackware.com/pub/slackware/slackware-14.1/source/xap/mozilla-firefox/mozilla-firefox.SlackBuild), seeing if that still works for a more recent non-ESR firefox might be another starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've managed to successfully install firefox 42.0, but I had to do so using [this script](https://gist.github.com/ruario/9672798).

I haven't had much of a chance to really study this script, so I'm not sure how it manages to accomplish a successful installation.

If you, on the other hand, *do* have a solid understanding of why ruario's script works and can sum it up succinctly, I'd be happy to dish out that +15 reputation.

Comment: I can probably answer since I wrote and maintain that script. Mozilla provide precompiled binaries for Linux in addition to source code. My script grabs the latest precompiled binary for your architecture. It then moves files around to their correct system wide install locations and creates the Slackware packaging meta data. Finally it produces a valid slackware package from this.